# Tomcat 9 Upgrade java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/file/ConfigurationSource

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, tomcat9

I have a working Tomcat 8 environment under Eclipse 4.9 IDE 2018‑09 and am trying to add a Tomcat 9 server to Eclipse for testing but upon Tomcat startup I am getting the following No Class Found error.  Previously a lib tomcat-util.jar was needed but that doesn't seem to exist with Tomcat 9.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/file/ConfigurationSource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:461)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigurationSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I've checked all the Tomcat9 libs and the class just seems to be missing

Comment: I have Tomcat 9 installed out of the box and it doesn't run even from the command like with a "catalina run".

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I might have had a bad download from a Tomcat mirror.  I re-downloaded version 9.0.14 from the tomcat archive and it works fine now. The ConfigurationSource class is in the tomcat-util.jar and the jar was missing from the download.

[Tomcat 9.0.14 archive download](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.14/bin/)